# android geofencing without calling requestlocationupdates

Tags: android, location, updates, geofencing

I am developing an app which is a geofencing based location awareness app. My concern is that will the geofencing will work without we programatically requesting the location updates by calling requestlocationupdates. In iOS when they request for region monitoring the OS will check for the location change internally using cell tower change, wifi..(not gps).and notify the app for exit or entry.

the google play services also does this internally ? or we have to request for location updates programatically ?

Comment: yes google play services do the same thing, But there is a setting in device for get location from network should be enabled.Google play services are running in background which can be used by all the application in device. So if you want to listen that in your application you need to set location listener in you app thats it.

Comment: I dont want to listen to the location updates. I just wanted to make sure that once we have added a geofence without my app or any other app requesting for location google play services will provide an exit or entry call back to my app. will that happen?

Comment: Nope that is even logically not possible.Because how google play service know that your app is looking for location. So you must say google service that I want locations by implementing interface.

Comment: No, I am adding a geofence and telling the play services to provide me a geofence exit or entry call back. Only that much. I am not requesting any location update. because i want to wake up my app only when I get a geofence exit or entry . If I kept listening for location updates  battery drain will occur.I dont want to do that. Whenever play services gets a location update through cell tower change or wifi It should tell is there any exit or entry event ?

Comment: @Maddy Have you solved this issue. Even I ran into similar issue.

Comment: @keen. No keen we have to call the requestlocation update with    'mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);'

Comment: I have the same problem. Is not a nice thing...